# Changing from NSMutableArray to AnyHashable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm currently migrating a project from Objective C to Swift 5.2. I have the following line in Objective C:`NSMutableArray *arrNewList = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Result"] mutableCopy];`, which returns a JSON like this:

```
{
        TotalLike = 31;
        Totalcomment = 18;
        "author_name" = "Scott Edward";
        "conv_message" = "They're spending the weekend at her mountain lodge";
        "conv_person_name" = Story;
        "conv_subscribe" = 1;
        "paid_free" = 0;
        "story_character" =         (
            Story,
            Abe,
            Kay
        );
        "story_cover" = "upload/story/image_5885bf86d2d1020170123023206.jpg";
        "story_id" = 9F6468ADD60FC678;
        "story_subtitle" = "";
        "story_title" = "Creepy House";
    }
```

When using Swiftify, and the corrections suggested by Xcode, I get the following line of code:

```
var arrNewList = ((responseObject as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["Result"]) as? [AnyHashable]
```

Which returns a json with the following format:

```
Optional([AnyHashable(
[AnyHashable("conv_person_name"): AnyHashable("Story"), 
AnyHashable("story_id"): AnyHashable("9F6468ADD60FC678"), 
AnyHashable("story_title"): AnyHashable("Creepy House"), 
AnyHashable("paid_free"): AnyHashable("0"), 
AnyHashable("author_name"): AnyHashable("Scott Edward"), 
AnyHashable("Totalcomment"): AnyHashable("18"), 
AnyHashable("TotalLike"): AnyHashable("31"), 
AnyHashable("story_subtitle"): AnyHashable(""), 
AnyHashable("story_character"): AnyHashable([AnyHashable("Story"), 
AnyHashable("Abe"), AnyHashable("Kay")]), 
AnyHashable("conv_message"): AnyHashable("They're spending the weekend at her mountain lodge"): AnyHashable("1"), 
AnyHashable("story_cover"): AnyHashable("upload/story/image_5885bf86d2d1020170123023206.jpg")]), AnyHashable([AnyHashable("paid_free"): AnyHashable("0"),
```

Whenever i try to access this JSON, my whole app crashed. I suspect it's due to the casting to "as [Anyhashable:any]", but i haven't been able to manage to do it correctly. Can anybody help me out, please?

Thank you!

Comment: try this let me know if works or not
var arrNewList = ((responseObject as? AnyObject)?["Result"]) as? NSMutableArray.

Comment: You can try this lib: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Use Codable, or at least real struct. Handling only Dictionaries/Array, that's bad idea. Don't just convert the Objective-C code, make it "Swifty". Avoid NSStuff (like NSMutableArray), prefers Swift array...